# Connection closed when trying to read an oracle Clob returned from procedure

Tags: java, oracle

I have an Oracle procedure with an input Clob and returns an output Clob.
When i'm trying to recover the value, i reach the object, if i try to read the toString fro the object, i take the  "oracle.sql.CLOB@625a8a83"   . But when i want to read the object, in anyways i tryed, allways get a connection closed exception.

in my code:

```
    MapSqlParameterSource parametros = new MapSqlParameterSource();

    // setting input parameter
    parametros.addValue("PE_IN", new SqlLobValue("IN DATA CLOB", new DefaultLobHandler()),
            Types.CLOB);

    // Executing call
    Map<String, Object> out = jdbcCall.execute(parametros);
    salida.setDatosRespuesta(out.get("PS_OUT").toString());
```

if i change the last line for this:

```
            Clob clob = (Clob) out.get("PS_OUT");     
            long len = clob.length();             
            String rtnXml = clob.getSubString(1, (int) len);
```

i get the connection close error. I tryed in several ways and i can't solve this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest to check this article: (http://www.kswaughs.com/2016/10/spring-stored-procedure-clob-out-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think yo are using the `SimpleJdbcCall` of the spring framework. If so the database configuration are the default configurations for the oracle driver, you need to increase the time out for the reading of the values for the connection. Check the [DatabaseMetaData](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html)  documentation, also check the [OracleConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_READ_TIMEOUT) properies `CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_READ_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT`. This happends because you are reading a large data from the database remember that de `CLOB` can have until 4gb of data

You need to keep in mind that is this process is very common in your application you need to consider the quantity of the connections to the database in order to have always enable connections to your database to guarantee your application availability

Regarding the `out.get("PS_OUT").toString()` this basically only show the [hash](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) that represents your object that the reason beacause why that line works fine

Comment: I couldn't solve it with that propertie. Finally i could do it with a rowmapper. Inside it, i could set the Clob content (text) to a String  that i could handle without th connection closed problem.